# Fourier series of $\cos^3 2x$ not in complex form

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

$\mathbf{f(x)=\cos^3 2x= \frac{1}{2}a_0+\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(a_n \cos nx + b_n \sin nx)}$

Since $\cos^3 2x$ is even $\rightarrow b_n=0$

$a_0=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi} \cos^3 2x$ $dx$

$a_0=\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_{0} \frac{1}{4}(\cos 6x+3 \cos 2x)$ $dx$

$a_0=\frac{1}{4\pi}[\frac{\sin 6x}{6}+\frac{3\sin 2x}{2} ]^{\pi}_{0}=0$

$a_n=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}(\cos 6x \cos nx)$ $dx$ $\frac{3}{4\pi}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}(\cos 2x \cos nx)= \frac{1}{4\pi}(\pi)+\frac{3}{4\pi}(\pi)=1$

I get $\cos^3 2x=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \cos nx$

The answer is

$\cos^3 2x=\frac{1}{4}(3\cos 2x+ \cos 6x)$

Comment: What do you desire: that we check ?  Your computation is exact...

Comment: You knew the answer at step #2... Why did you do the rest of the calculations?

Comment: @N74, do you mean after step 2, I should not write all that, could you please explain why I should not write it?

Comment: You expanded $ \cos^3 2x$ as $\frac{1}{4}(\cos 6x+3 \cos 2x)$. Now directly compare this with the generic taylor series to find $a_2$ and $a_6$.